# adb shell am instrument process crashed

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to run an espresso black box test on a 3rd party apk file using a test apk file. I've set the testApplicationId in the build.gradle, and the targetPackage in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here's the commands I run:

```
adb install app-debug.apk
Success
adb install app-debug-androidTest.apk
Success
adb shell am instrument -w com.example.android.testing.espresso.WikipediaTester/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

Here's the tomcat log:

```
09-11 22:22:17.065  8576  8576 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
09-11 22:22:17.098  8576  8576 W app_process: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-11 22:22:17.116  8576  8576 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
09-11 22:22:17.118  1510  2317 I ActivityManager: Force stopping org.wikipedia.alpha appid=10102 user=0: start instr
09-11 22:22:17.123  8586  8586 I zygote  : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-11 22:22:17.130  1510  2317 I ActivityManager: Start proc 8586:org.wikipedia.alpha/u0a102 for added application org.wikipedia.alpha
09-11 22:22:17.131  8586  8586 W zygote  : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-11 22:22:17.149  8586  8586 W zygote  : Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/app/org.wikipedia.alpha-X9wevNAQOGt3rTh-c4Ydpg==/base.apk
09-11 22:22:17.149  8586  8586 W zygote  : NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
09-11 22:22:17.149  8586  8586 W zygote  : Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;' in /data/app/org.wikipedia.alpha-X9wevNAQOGt3rTh-c4Ydpg==/base.apk and /data/app/com.example.android.testing.espresso.WikipediaTester-iiYiial_oKwqZvmMrjx_Zw==/base.apk
09-11 22:22:17.149  8586  8586 W zygote  : 
09-11 22:22:17.279  8586  8586 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
09-11 22:22:17.281  8586  8586 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.wikipedia.alpha, PID: 8586
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.example.android.testing.espresso.WikipediaTester/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5730)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5728)
09-11 22:22:17.282  8586  8586 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
09-11 22:22:17.284  8586  8586 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 8586 SIG: 9
09-11 22:22:17.328  1510  1522 I ActivityManager: Process org.wikipedia.alpha (pid 8586) has died: fore FGS 
09-11 22:22:17.329  1510  1522 W ActivityManager: Crash of app org.wikipedia.alpha running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.example.android.testing.espresso.WikipediaTester/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
09-11 22:22:17.329  1510  1522 I ActivityManager: Force stopping org.wikipedia.alpha appid=10102 user=0: finished inst
09-11 22:22:17.330  1510  8604 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
09-11 22:22:17.330  1510  8604 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
09-11 22:22:17.330  1510  8604 W Binder  :  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:736)
09-11 22:22:17.330  1510  8604 W Binder  :  at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:160)
09-11 22:22:17.330  1510  8604 W Binder  :  at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
09-11 22:22:17.331  8576  8576 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out, moved from androidTest to main

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by "moved from androidTest to main". Moved what? I'm having the same problem and cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Mambazo i'd be quite surprised if the OP moved instrumented tests classes (as I believe those were the ones he/she wanted to run) to "main" bundle. Why would that work?